# How to scan string from file and store it on an array of strings (two-dimensional array)?

Tags: c, arrays, file-handling, filehandle

I am scanning a string from a file and storing it into an array of strings. When I compile my program, it does not produce any error but when I run it, it says `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I know that the error is in the fscanf statement, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

My code looks like this:

```
 FILE    *stringsIn = fopen("strings.txt", "rt");
 char    *strings[INPUT_STRINGS];

    for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_STRINGS; i++)
            fscanf(stringsIn, "%s ", &strings[i][0]);
```

Comment: A string is a null terminated array of *characters*. The only atrray you have in your program is an array of *pointers*.  For a pointer to be usable in functions like `fscanf`,  it needs to *point somewhere*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of pointers but you didn't allocate space for each string. In this case what you can do is preallocate a big enough buffer or read in a preallocated buffer, see how many characters were read and allocate a string of that size.

```
FILE    *stringsIn = fopen("strings.txt", "rt");
char    *strings[INPUT_STRINGS];

for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_STRINGS; i++) {
   strings[i] = (char*)malloc(2048); //allocate a big enough buffer
   fscanf(stringsIn, "%2047s ", &strings[i][0]);
}
```

The second version is something like:

```
FILE    *stringsIn = fopen("strings.txt", "rt");
char    *strings[INPUT_STRINGS];
char temp[2048];

for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_STRINGS; i++) {
   fscanf(stringsIn, "%2047s ", &temp);
   size_t len = strlen(temp);
   strings[i] = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
   strncpy(strings[i], temp, len);
}
```

Comment: Never use `"%s"` without specifying a width to limit the number of characters to read. *`malloc(len)`* off-by-one.

Comment: "*`strncpy(strings[i], temp, len);`*": Why not just `strcpy(strings[i], temp)`?! `strnpcy()`'s usage is so error prone, you should yourself in the foot so easyly, as the code you show unfortunately demonstrates.

Comment: Also: Do not cast the result of `malloc()` & friends in C.

Comment: I dont understand why there is a (char *) before malloc. Can you please explain it?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/ in the documentation it says that malloc returns void*, so i cast the result to char*. I think that some newer compilers don’t need that.